# ASP.Net, jQuery, Ajax and a parseError

Tags: asp.net, wcf, jquery

I have tried to see if there is anything on this great site for this (and there probably is), so I am sorry if I have missed it.

Anyway, I am calling a WCF endpoint using jQuery Ajax under ASP.Net.

The Web service call is working fine in Fiddler and returns the following data:

```
    {"d": {"__type":"ProcessedTotals:#","DailyError":"0","DailyProcessed":"0","TotalError":"48","TotalProcessed":"70"}}
```

This is my code

```
     function GetData() {
        alert('Ajax Start');

        $.ajax({
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "json",
            url: "http://localhost/abc123/WebManagement.svc/ReturnTotals",
            success: (function (data) {

                alert(data[0].TotalProcessed);

                //$("#TotRecs").html(data.d.TotalProcessed);
                //$("#TotErr").html(data.d.TotalError);
                //$("#DayTot").html(data.d.DailyProcessed);
                //$("#DayErr").html(data.d.DailyError);

            }),
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {

                alert("FAILED:" + status);
            }

        })

        alert('Ajax End');
    }
```

Whilst debugging in Firefox the line that causes the error is SUCCESS:

I know that it is using JSONP, as I am having to access the data from a different website.

Thanks

Paul

Comment: What error is your console in firefox showing?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: "http://localhost/abc123/WebManagement.svc/ReturnTotals",
        success: (function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        })
    });
```

You were doing some weird stuff there. Trying to send an empty object literal along with the call, which doesn't make any sense. Also, your error callback won't work with a jsonp request. Try the above, it should work fine. If not, please mention the error that you're getting.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have changed the code to what you have above and it still does the same.

Comment: You really have to tell us what error you're getting. It's hard to say anything useful beyond this point without knowing what the error is.

Comment: My problem Hans is that I don't know enough about jQuery to give you that.

Comment: "Whilst debugging in Firefox the line that causes the error is SUCCESS:". If you know the line that causes the error, the message of the error will be displayed right next to it. That's the thing we're looking for.